# Tarmac or Pavement (US English)

Tags: word-choice, word-request

When you pave a road it should be called a pavement. In UK a pavement is used to describe what in US is called the sidewalk.

Is the black paved road in US called: pavement, tarmac, both, or if not what then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.S., "pavement" normally is used to refer to the stuff that the road is made from, or to the surface of the road, and not to the road as a whole. That is, no one says, "I got lost on the pavement to Toledo". We say, "I got lost on the road to Toledo" or "... on the highway to Toledo." We do say, "The construction workers laid down new pavement" or "The condition of the pavement on Elm Street is very bad." Or, "Bob was hurt when he fell out of the back of the truck and landed on the pavement."

We also sometimes use the word to refer to a paved area in contrast to an unpaved area. Like, "Please don't park your car on the grass -- park on the pavement." But as I say, this wouldn't be used to distinguish a paved road from an unpaved road, it's generally limited to talking about a parking area, or to the paved surface of the road as opposed to areas along the side of the road. "He lost control of the car and ran off the pavement and onto the sidewalk."

If we want to distinguish a paved road from an unpaved road, we say "paved road" and "unpaved road", or we might be more specific and say "gravel road" or "dirt road" or whatever.

As phenry says, "tarmac" is pretty much only used to refer to paved areas at an airport other than runways and taxiways.

If the usage is different in other English-speaking countries ... I wouldn't know. Well, I understand that in the U.K. they use the word "yard" to refer to a paved area, like a parking lot. In the U.S., a "yard" is an area with grass and trees around a house. A British person discussing language differences once posed the question, "How often does the average person in Britain mow a yard?" The answer being never. Why would you mow a yard? An American, though, mows his yard about once a week during the summer.

Comment: Jay, I think that the British equivalent of an American *yard* is a *garden*. In the UK, *tarmac* is the black stuff used to make the surface of a road that traffic travels on. It's also used as the surface for some driveways and the short, private roads leading to buildings other than houses.

Comment: I really enjoyed reading your answer @Jay, it's excellent.

Comment: ++ But I never mow my yard; I mow my lawn. (And I wouldn't do that if my son weren't off at college.)

Answer (score 6):

In the US, almost all the roads are paved in most cities and other developed areas, so we usually just say *roads* and *streets* when talking about the routes themselves. When it is necessary to discuss the road surface specifically, it is usually called [*asphalt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asphalt), at least when the surface of the road is dark.

*Tarmac*, oddly enough, is used specifically in the US to refer to the large paved area used to load and unload aircraft at airports, formally known as the [apron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airport_apron). *Pavement* usually applies to any paved surface.

Comment: Ironically, those airport aprons are usually paved with concrete, not tarmacadam.

Comment: @choster Amusing point. 'Not the only case of that sort of thing. We routinely refer to a thin foil made from aluminum as "tin foil", even though it has no tin in it. And we talk about "dialing a phone" even though it has no dial but rather push buttons. Etc.

Comment: @choster And the black stuff we laymen call "asphalt" is called "oil" by the guys who actually lay it down.

Comment: To me, your comments with more of this stuff qualify for an interesting article to ESL readers.